# camel-test-spring / spring-boot-starter-test / mock external Rest webservice using JUNIT

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, apache-camel

I am trying to write Junit tests to test my camel route which is calling an external REST webservice.
The route is defined like this:

```
    @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            super.configure();
            
            from(ENDPOINT).routeId(ROUTE_ID)
            .log("referentiel.point_vente.unit...${header.code_pvente}...${header.type_pvente}...on " + referentielApiBaseUrl)
            .to("log:rechPVente_unit_IN?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
            
            .setHeader("host", constant(null)) // service unvailble 503
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_SERVLET_REQUEST, constant(null))
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_SERVLET_RESPONSE, constant(null))
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, constant(null))
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URL, constant(null))
            .setHeader("CamelServletContextPath", constant(null))
            .setBody(constant(null))
            
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))       // operation de type GET
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH, simple("/referentiel/point_vente/${header.code_pvente}/${header.type_pvente}"))      // route sur ReferentielAPI permettant la recuperation des donnees de l'entite gestionnaire (code, libelle, email)
            
            .to("log:rechPVente_unit_avtU?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
            
            .toD(  referentielApiBaseUrl )
    
            .choice()
            .when(simple("${header.CamelHttpResponseCode} >= 400"))// en cas de hhtpfailed perte de header initiaux!
                .to("log:failed_rechPVente?showBody=false&showHeaders=true")
                .setHeader("code_pvente", simple("${header.code_pvente}"))
                .setHeader("type_pvente", simple("${header.type_pvente}"))
                .setHeader("error_code", simple("${header.CamelHttpResponseCode}"))
                .to("direct:" + ErrorGenericRoute.ROUTE_ID)
            .otherwise()
                .to("log:RetourRefApiTechPVente?showBody=true&showHeaders=true");
        }
```

The url reached is this one: https4://referentiel-technique-staging.apps.api.saprr.local.

I want to test this route band mock the webservice call so that it is not called. In my mock, I would like to return a fake response so that de process continue and I can verify that the response at the end of the process is as I want.

The fake response I wxant to return is:

```
> {
>"entiteGestionnaire":
>   {
>    "email":"franchise-peage@aprr.fr                 ",
>    "libelle":"FRANCHISE DE PEAGE","code":"009"
>   },
>"numeroAbonne":"250090702823"
>}
>
```

I tried this but I think ther's something I misunderstood:

```
    @RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
    @MockEndpoints
    @UseAdviceWith
    @SpringBootTest(classes = fr.aprr.api.mailbot.Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
    public class PointVenteRechercherUnitTest extends BaseTests {
    
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PointVenteRechercherUnitTest.class);
    
        @Autowired
        private FluentProducerTemplate template;
    
        @Value("${mailbotmetier.urlto.apitech.referentiel}")
        private String referentielApiBaseUrl;
    
        @Test
        public void referentielpointDeVenteCallTest() throws Exception {
    
            context.getRouteDefinition(PointVenteRechercherUnit.ROUTE_ID).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {
                    // weaveByType(ToDynamicDefinition.class).replace().setBody(new
                    // ConstantExpression(ClientTestUtil.getJsonClient()));
                    // replaceFromWith("direct:PointVenteRechercherUnit.ROUTE_ID");
                    // send the outgoing message to mock:out
    
                    interceptSendToEndpoint("https://.*").skipSendToOriginalEndpoint().setBody(simple("toto"));
    
                    weaveAddLast().to("mock:resultat");
                }
    
            });
            context.start();
    
            MockEndpoint mockOut = context.getEndpoint("mock:resultat", MockEndpoint.class);
            mockOut.expectedMessageCount(1);
    
            String result = template.withHeader("code_pvente", "009").withHeader("type_pvente", "GG")
                    .to("direct:" + PointVenteRechercherUnit.ROUTE_ID).request(String.class);
    
            logger.info("************** LU  A LA FIN *************** : " + result);
    
            context.stop();
    
            mockOut.assertIsSatisfied();
    
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Stéphane

Comment: I have the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60829282/test-rest-endpoint-camel-3-spring-boot?rq=1